# How to toggle two commandlink without refresh the whole page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, commandlink

I am having a pageblock in which pageblock sectionitems of 2 commandlinks. I want to toggle between the these two links without getting the page refreshed.

VF Page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showFilter").click(function(){
        $("hideFilter").toggle();
    });
});

<apex:pageblock>
<div style="width:35%;" id="maindiv">
              <apex:pageblocksection >
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputlabel value="Account Filters"/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
               <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:commandLink value="Show Filter" id="showFilter"/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
               <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                  <apex:commandLink value="Hide Filter" id="hideFilter" style="display:none;"/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
              </apex:pageblocksection> 
              </div>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Answer (score 4):

The thing you're getting wrong is you cannot use literal `id` attributes from Visualforce tags. They get prefixed, as described in [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) and other resources. You can use the "ends with" selector instead, if you prefer.

**Failing Selector**

```
$("#literalId")
```

**Working Selector**

```
$("[id$='literalId']")
```

Even better, however, is to use a class selector instead:

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="showFilter" ... />

// ...
var $showLink = $(".showFilter");
```

---

Beyond that, this question is just basic Javascript functionality no different than you would find on any other website.

Comment: Using a class selector would be another viable alternative. I prefer that because it's a bit more legible (imho).

Comment: I do too, was going to add that but got distracted.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can use `$Component` if you add ids to the whole element stack, but have to use `document.querySelector` because Salesforce uses `:` in their ids, which get misinterpreted as `jQuery` 
selectors if they aren't escaped: `$(document.querySelector('#{!$Component.pageBlockID...showFilter}'))`